# How to install python on a WIndows server 2016 on ec2 instance

Tags: windows-server-2016

I am trying to install `python-2.7.14.amd64.msi` on a Windows Server 2016 on a ec2 instance

Version info: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter

[image]

Why I cannot install python on this server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/523254/windows-installer-does-not-permit-installation-from-a-remote).

> Everyone seems to think that the \tsclient\ is a regular network share. But it is not! It's a feature of Terminal Services service. However, if you find yourself in the position where you must use the mapped drives for installing software, either copy the software first, or map the \tsclient\ first.
>
> To map run this command:

```
net use * \\tsclient\<drive>
```

> then install from the network mapped drive.. seems the installer does not check the actual path to the mapped drive

Related Microsoft KB article [here.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927063/error-message-when-you-try-to-install-a-msi-package-on-a-windows-serve)